# Puppeteer renders ALL HTML Content but only gets some tags

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am web scraping using NodeJS/typescript.

I have a problem using puppeteer where I get the fully rendered page (which I verify by running `await page.content()`). I printed the content and found that it had 26 'a' tags (links). However, when I search with puppeteer, I only get 20.

What is more strange is that sometimes I will get all the 'a' tags on the page and sometimes it gets less 'a' tags than on the page - all without changing the code! It seems to be kind of random.

I've seen some suggestions online saying to use a `waitForElement` method or something along those lines. Basically, before searching for tags, it ensures an element is on the page. I don't think this would help in my case because clearly puppeteer is getting everything it needs as shown by the `await page.content()` method.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? Thanks! A simplified snippet of my code is below.

```
const getLinksFromPage = async (
    browser: puppeteer.Browser,
    url: string
) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const curLink = book.sportsURLs[pageIndex];
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkIdle0'});

    const html = await page.content();    // this code gets the content and prints it 
    console.log(html);                    // so I can verify number of 'a' tags

    const rawLinks = await page.$$eval('a', (elements: Element[]) => {
        return elements
            .map((element: Element) => element.getAttribute('href')!)
    });

    await page.close();
    return rawLinks
};
```

Comment: I'd need to see the page to say more, but if you're expecting some number of tags, you can use `waitForFunction` and check the tag length.

Comment: Is it also possible that you are counting `<a>` tags that do not have the `href` attribute on them, and when you are doing your `.map` its only giving you the ones that do have that attribute?